# Collision Detection using Box2d(for Android)?

Tags: java, android, box2d, collision

Can someone explain the in what way works the collision detection using box2d for android. I cannot understand in what way works BBContactListener.

```
BBContactListener listener = new BBContactListener();
world = new BBWorld(gravity, doSleep);
world.SetContactListener(listener);
```

How to use that listener? Should I extend standart to create my own or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not use box2d for android, but I think the idea is the same there. You have to implement contact processing methods. That's the way to do it in C++.

```
class ContactListener : public b2ContactListener
{
public:
    ContactListener();
    ~ContactListener();

    void BeginContact(b2Contact *contact) {...}
    void EndContact(b2Contact *contact) {...}
    void PreSolve (b2Contact *contact, const b2Manifold *oldManifold) {...}
    void PostSolve (b2Contact *contact, const b2ContactImpulse *impulse) {...}
};
```

Then just pass this class to `b2World'

Comment: So as i understand i have create my listener, implement methods, than i have to create myb2World property in the listener, activate listener(myb2World.SetContactListener(this)). So all manipulations(collisions, impulses, etc.) with visual objects will be implemented in these 4 methods?

Comment: @GeorgeBuron: These methods will be called automatically by b2World for every collision. Note, however, you are not able to do all the stuff you want in these methods because they are called during b2World::Step function execution. So you are not able for example to create or remove bodies in this functions

Comment: So as i see these methods are to impelement reflections or something like this. And where should i delete objects during contact? p.s.thank you really for information bacause could find nothing )

Comment: @GeorgeBuron: What do you meen by reflections? You have to store somewhere the information about objects you want to delete. And delete them after Step function is finished